# Feed Dialog not working on some browsers

Tags: facebook, sdk, dialog, feed, fb.ui

Hi guys I have a weird problem with de feed dialog.
It works pefect on Firefox, but when I try to use it on IE or Chrome I got this error "*An error occurred. Please try later*"

I have tried to fix it but I can't. Can you help me please. 
This is the code i'm using to call the dialog.

```
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js'></script>
<a href="#" onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post Feed</a>


    <script> 
    FB.init({appId: "xxxx", status: true, cookie: true});
    function postToFeed() {
           // calling the API ...
            var obj = {
              method: 'feed',
              link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/xxxx',
              picture: 'xxxx',
              name: 'xxxx',
              caption: 'xxxxx',
              description: 'xxxxx',
              properties: [{text: 'xx', href: 'xx'},],
              actions: [{name: 'xx', link: 'xx'}],
            };

            function callback(response) {
              document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Well Done!!";
            }

            FB.ui(obj, callback);
          }

        </script>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:

1: It could possibly be as simple as the rogue comma in your code here after actions:

```
actions: [{name: 'xx', link: 'xx'}],
```

Try removing that, however Chrome should better handle that, but that would have caused an issue with IE!

2: Use the Console to see if any errors are thrown.

3: Add oauth: true to your init statement like so:

```
FB.init({appId: "xxxx", status: true, cookie: true, oauth: true});
```

4: Remove the parameters in the call, and add them back in one by one after testing it works with each addition: start with:

```
var obj = {
              method: 'feed',
              link: 'http://apps.facebook.com/xxxx',
              picture: 'xxxx',
              name: 'xxxx',
              caption: 'xxxxx',
              description: 'xxxxx'
            };
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I found the promblem the script collides with the code of a social pluggin.